# Ionic4 can not make https call to REST api on android device

Tags: android, angular, https, ionic5

I have an ionic5 application that makes calls to REST api hosted on my server. When testing the application with browser everything works fine. But after deploying to real android device the api call returns status (canceled) with initiator polyfills-es5.js and seems that the call doesn't even start.
Initially I had an ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED error but after adding a ssl certificate to the server (zerossl) this error disappeared but instead the https calls return the canceled status.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Comment: Unfortunately no, as I had this kind of problem previously, so I have tried all of the methods mentioned in the post. Nothing worked. So I added secure protocol (with zerossl certificate) to my server and all the calls to api are made with https protocol. Now I don't have  Cleartext error but the api calls are simply canceled.